# Intersection of union of different types is not what I expected

Tags: typescript, types, operator-precedence, union-types, intersection-types

```js
type T1 = 1 | 'b' & string | number // "b" | number
type T2 = 1 | 2 & 1 | 3 // 1 | 3
```

I'm new to TS. Can someone tell me why it's `"b" | number` and  `1 | 3` and what's going on here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### `&` has higher precedence than `|`

Thus your code is interpreted as:

```js
type T1 = 1 | ('b' & string) | number 
type T2 = 1 | (2 & 1) | 3
```

in which case `"b" | number` and `1 | 3` make sense.

If you add parenthesis it will work the way you have in mind:

```js
type T1 = (1 | 'b') & (string | number) // 1 | "b"
type T2 = (1 | 2) & (1 | 3) // 1
```

Comment: The higher precedence of `&` is intuitive as it follows all other uses of that operator relative to `|`